# Eslint in Visual studio code not working with .hbs files?

Tags: ember.js, visual-studio-code, eslint

Ive got eslint installed in visual studio code and it works for .js files but with Ember's .hbs files no errors are shown in the code editor. I have it all enabled along with eslint packages installed. I am running Version 1.29.0 on Mac os.

Answer (score 2):

eslint works with .js files. For .hbs files, I recommend ember-template-lint.

https://github.com/ember-template-lint/ember-template-lint

Comment: Is this something i would install globally or do i need to install it directly to my project?

Comment: I generally recommend installing it in your project to share it with your team and include in CI. The latest version of ember-cli includes it for you.